# How to make use of index on DELETE multiple rows on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has about 9M rows, and I want to delete about 270K rows. I have an SQL that works but can’t make use of my index, so it fails on resources.

I have multiple rows per day (created_at), for each exchange/base_currency/quote_currency pair.

My columns are :

```
Id  exchange    base_currency       quote_currency  created_at
```

My indexes are :

```
ix1 id

Ix2 exchange    base_currency       quote_currency  created_at
```

For each exchange/base_currency/quote_currency pair, I want to keep the latest row (latest id or created_at) of that day. So I find all the MAX(id) for each day/exchange/base_currency/quote_currency, then I try to remove all rows that weren't selected (NOT IN).

My query is :

```
DELETE FROM `tickers` 
WHERE
      DATE(`created_at`) = '2018-06-26'
  AND id  NOT IN 
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM (select * FROM `tickers`) as t2 
          WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = '2018-06-26'
         GROUP BY
          exchange
         , base_currency
         , quote_currency
         , DATE(created_at)
        )
```

The SELECT MAX(id) makes use of the ix2 index because of the GROUP BY, but I think the DELETE does a tablescan to pick up the rows with DATE(`created_at`) = '2018-06-26', which is slow.

Any way to structure this query so I use the ix2 index on the DELETE too? Or should I create another index on created_at only?

Comment: What type the column `created_at` is?

Comment: Created_at is a timestamp

Comment: How often will you execute this query? Or how fast do you need it to be?

Comment: It's going to have to be multiple times a day from now on to consistently clean the old stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use an index you would need to do two things:

1. Create an index for `created_at`:

   ```
   create index ix3 on `tickers` (`created_at`);
   ```
2. Avoid using a formula on the where condition by rephrasing it. For example, use `between` instead:

   ```
   DELETE FROM `tickers` 
   WHERE
         `created_at` between '2018-06-26T00:00:00' and '2018-06-26T23:59:59'
     AND id  NOT IN 
       (SELECT MAX(id) FROM (select * FROM `tickers`) as t2 
             WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = '2018-06-26'
            GROUP BY
             exchange
            , base_currency
            , quote_currency
            , DATE(created_at)
           )
   ```

However, you are deleting an important percentage of the table (3%?). When this happens, the database engine may ignore the index and prefer a full table scan anyway.

You'll need to test and see what the database goes for.

Comment: Super, will test that, will let you know

Comment: Created the proposed index, SELECT queries were faster, but was having problems with the DELETE query. Changed it from a WHERE NOT IN to a LEFT JOIN, see solution here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561606/mysql-delete-with-not-in-subselect-not-using-index-and-getting-error-1205-hy0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561606/mysql-delete-with-not-in-subselect-not-using-index-and-getting-error-1205-hy0) . Thanks for your help!